# How can I get the video's thumbnail using ytdl.getInfo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am using ytdl-core and discord.js to create a discord bot, and am adding a music command. Is there a way using ytdl.getInfo that I can get the thumbnail of the provided URL?

Edit:

```
let validate = await ytdl.validateURL(args[0])
    if(!validate) return message.channel.send("This URL doesn't seem to be valid. Please put a valid YouTube URL after the command.")
    let vidInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0])
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can
By just running `ytdl.getInfo()` you can find that one of the first property of the object is `thumbnail_url`. So it would be

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

ytdl.getInfo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A', function(err, info) {
  console.log(info.thumbnail_url) // "Adele - Hello" thumbail
});
```

Howver the default thumbnail is really small. So I went on the video and found (by inspecting the element) that the picture used for the backrground is the same as the default one, but with 'hqdefault' instead of 'default' in the name.

Example:
Adele Hello thumbnail: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YQHsXMglC9A/default.jpg
Adele Hello hq thumbnail: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YQHsXMglC9A/hqdefault.jpg

I don't know if it apply to all video tho. I think you can do something like, try hq thumbnail, if not found use default thumbnail.

Edit: Adele Hello maxres thumbnail: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YQHsXMglC9A/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 1):

if you look very well to the links, you see that both of them are created like https://i.ytimg.com/vi/video_id/default.jpg, so if you have the ID of the video you can easily define it as a variable and put it in the link just like

```
let videoID = //however you want to get the ID
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/${videoID}/default.jpg
```